# Storing Access Token and Refresh Token on Xamarin

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin, local-storage, oauth-2.0

I have a WebApi 2 using ASP.Net Identity. I want to consume this in a Xamarin application, I'm struggling to find a straight answer to this question:

How can i store the Access Token and Refresh token on the device using Xamarin, similar to Cookies or Session state in ASP.NET?

I'm able to make the call to get these tokens, but i'm new to Xamarin and can't work out how to save them on the device so the user doesn't need to constantly login.

The targets devices are Windows, iOS and Android

Comment: Use James's settings plugin https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Settings

Comment: Did anyone figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

[XLabs](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Platform/XLabs.Platform.iOS/Services/SecureStorage.cs).Platform has ISecureStorage interface and implementations for iOS/Droid/WP8 with native encrypted storages.
Also You could take a look at the [Akavache](https://github.com/reactiveui/Akavache) SecureBlobCache.
Every time Access Token Expired, use Refresh Token TO Gain new Access TOken(Maybe new Refresh TOken)Then replace them ...

Answer (score 0):

We can use **Xamarin.Auth** to store data in the account store like below.

**Storing Account Information**

```
public void SaveCredentials (string userName, string password)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (userName) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (password)) {
    Account account = new Account {
      Username = userName
    };
    account.Properties.Add ("Password", password);
    AccountStore.Create ().Save (account, App.AppName);
  }
}
```

**Retrieving Account Information**

```
public string UserName {
  get {
    var account = AccountStore.Create ().FindAccountsForService (App.AppName).FirstOrDefault ();
    return (account != null) ? account.Username : null;
  }
}

public string Password {
  get {
    var account = AccountStore.Create ().FindAccountsForService (App.AppName).FirstOrDefault ();
    return (account != null) ? account.Properties ["Password"] : null;
  }
}
```